# DbContext - passing custom configuration option

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I have .NET Core 6 web application with Entity Framework.

My DbContext is something like:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContextDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
        // How to set it from configuration options
        this.HasCustomFeature = ...
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I pass `HasCustomFeature` over configuration options when using:

```
services.AddDbContext<Model.MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

...so I could read it in constructor? Generally `HasCustomFeature` setting value comes from my application options that are external to DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit simplified but `AddDbContext` basically registers the context and the options in DI ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/bfc91dcbfe7f2507e8c838d26d0f0c0922559d4f/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L605)) so you can add parameters to context ctor to be resolved from the DI. So probably the easiest option would be to just add another ctor parameter and register the corresponding service in the DI. For example:

```cs
public class MyCustomOptions
{
    public bool HasCustomFeature { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> opts, MyCustomOptions myOpts):base(opts)
    {
         this.HasCustomFeature = myOpts.HasCustomFeature;
    }
}
```

And registration:

```cs
// sample registration, can be bound from config, using options pattern etc.
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(new MyCustomOptions
{
    HasCustomFeature = true
});
services.AddDbContext<Model.MyDbContext>(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a configuration model to represent the custom configuration option:

   ```
   public class MyOptions
   {
       public bool HasCustomFeature { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Bind the custom option from the configuration to your `MyOptions` model in the Program.cs:

   ```
   builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(
       builder.Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
   builder.Services.AddDbContext<MvcProj6_0Context>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.")));
   ```
3. Modify your `DbContext` constructor to accept `IOptions<MyOptions>` and use it to set the `HasCustomFeature` property:

   ```
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
   {
       private readonly bool _hasCustomFeature;

       public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IOptions<MyOptions> customFeatureSettings)
           : base(options)
       {
           _hasCustomFeature = customFeatureSettings.Value.HasCustomFeature;
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```

Be sure define a custom configuration section in your `appsettings.json` (or other configuration source).

For example:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "your_connection_string_here"
  },
  "MyOptions": {
    "HasCustomFeature": true
  }
}
```